# Indian citizens living abroad, renew passport in India

Tags: indian-citizens, passports, germany, passport-stamps, passport-renewals

I am an Indian citizen living in Germany (with Residence Permit), I can renew my passport in Germany. But, I will be in India for 3 months and I can also easily renew my passport in India.

If I choose to do it in India, will this affect my entry back to Germany, given that I won't have the stamps while leaving Germany and stamps on entry to India?

---

PS: It is significantly cheaper to do it from India.

Answer (score 2):

As long your passport is valid during your departure, you can renew it in India. You can apply for the renewal of the existing passport up to a year prior to the current passport’s expiry.

However, I strongly recommend carrying both passports with you while coming back to Germany. If custom control questions on your stamp, you can clearly show them the old one and the renewed one.

You can do online before visiting India too and then be there on time.

https://www.bankbazaar.com/passport/passport-renewal.html

Comment: I think one is required to surrender the old passport

Comment: @Nikhil I'm not sure what the rules in India are, but in most countries your old passport will be cancelled (generally by punching holes in it) and returned to you along with the new one.

Comment: @Nikhil: As per my understanding, you will get your old passport too. https://www.immihelp.com/nri/indianpassport/indian-passport-renewal.html

Comment: In some countries you need to ask for it or mark it on the form/site.

Answer (score 1):

Your new Indian passport will have old passport number (on the address page, at the bottom). Old passport will be canceled by cancel stamp on first page and it will be punched so that it can not be used in any machine readable device.

However, **you HAVE to carry your old passport** along with new one (specially when it has ongoing visa). Your ongoing visa will still be valid even if you renew your passport. It doesn't matter if you have entry stamps in old passport or new, as far as you have valid passport and valid visa, you can travel to respective country.

At the immigration gate, just present your ALL passports (new + old) to the officer and you are good to go.